# How to run a javascript JSON Schema to a JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js

I'm new to Javascript and JSON Schemas, and I have a question how to make it run... I have created a Schema, I have a JSON Schema validator [here](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv) , and a JSON Object. I've been told to write a  Javascript function which takes a JSON schema and some JSON and than return whether the validation succeeded or not(and if not, which key was problematic).

Thing is that I don't know if I can test this on a HTML with the console(just calling the .js file with the schema, JSON object and function), if I have to use node.js for this type of tasks with JSON or... So far I've installed the lib and I've created a HTML to "test" it; but errors on the console don't fit to a non-valid schema or something. Can somebody give me some orientation? Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <title></title>

  </head>
  <body>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="schema.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to paste all of the relevant code...

Comment: Just want to know how to start testing all of it; cause I'm little bit confused with node.js and stuff :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run some quick tests, the path of least resistance would be a) to run it in your web console (open developer tools in Chrome for example) or b) create a file (say, 'test.js') and run `node test.js` on your command line:

```
var testSchema = {
  name: {
    type: 'string'
  },
  age: {
    type: 'number'
  }
};

var testData = {
  name: 'john',
  age: 47
};

function checkAgainstSchema(data, schema) {
  return Object.keys(data).every(function(key) {
    return typeof testData[key] === schema[key].type;
  });
}

checkAgainstSchema(testData, testSchema); // => true
```

Hard to give more information than that with the limited amount of info you've provided in your question. Maybe the above will give you something to start with.

FYI, the above is not a robust implementation of what you're asking for, but instead is just a simple example of what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [tonicdev.com](https://tonicdev.com/npm/ajv) to play with ajv you've used (or any other npm package).

Answer (score 0):

There is a module to parse and verify JSON data against JSON schemas: [tv4](https://github.com/geraintluff/tv4). If you're using node.js, it's available via

```
npm install tv4
```